# How to create Spine model without auto-reposting ajax event to server by Spine

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dom-events, spine.js

I did try spinejs mvc library recently, from the their docs API said that, every time we create new object of Spine Model, Spine will send an ajax event called "created" to server. It's good for synchronize data between new object at client and save back to server.

But in case of fetching objects from sever and push to Spine model, I don't need to re-send "create" event to server, because objects were saved in sever DB already.

Are there some way to disable this behavior (auto-postback event when changed spine model to sever) of Spine?
Or are there some ways to fetch objects from server and push (save) to Spine Model without calling create object and send back "create" ajax event to server?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Ajax docs](http://spinejs.com/docs/ajax):

> Ajax requests are sent automatically whenever any model records are created, updated or deleted. You can prevent this behavior (i.e. stopping a DELETE request going out when a record is destroyed) by using Ajax.disable(function)

```
Spine.Ajax.disable ->
  record.destroy()
```